# SQL: Fetch rows having a column (group by column) being the MAX value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to know how to retrieve rows matching the maximum value for a column.

```
SCHEMA

assignments:
id  student_id   subject_id
1   10           1
2   10           2
3   20           1
4   30           3
5   30           3
6   40           2

students:
id  name
10   A
20   B
30   C

subjects:
id  name
1   Math
2   Science
3   English
```

Queries:
Provide the SQL for:

```
1. Display the names of the students who have taken most number of assignments
2. Display the names of the subjects which have been taken the most number of times
```

Results:

```
1. 
  A
  C

2. 
  Math
  English
```

Thanks !

Comment: Heheehhe, no :) Was just thinking around and came across something that I quite not understood. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer is not quite right - you won't get the instances where there are two with the same count.  Try this - the second will be easy to replicate once understand the concept.

```
SELECT a.student_id, s.name, COUNT(a.subject_id) as taken_subjects
FROM assignments a
INNER JOIN students s ON a.student_id = s.id
GROUP BY a.student_id, s.name
HAVING COUNT(a.subject_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM assignments GROUP BY student_id LIMIT 1)
```

Alternate query:
SELECT a.subject_id, s.subject_name, COUNT(a.subject_id) FROM assignment a, subjects s
WHERE a.subject_id = s.subject_id
GROUP BY a.student_id, s.subject_name
HAVING COUNT(a.subject_id) = (SELECT MAX(COUNT(1)) FROM assignment GROUP BY subject_id)

Comment: Did you forget `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` in your subquery?

Comment: Yep, that I what I thought as well. Was just wondering if they would be another way to do this. Thanks though,